# Get current logged in user and display it on the Site as "Hello (Username)"

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, javascript, html

I am using SharePoint 2013 Online and I'm looking for some JavaScript and html to display the current logged in user on the site like for example:

> Hello (Username)

If anyone could help or just point myself in the correct direction it will be a help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var loginName = "";
var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
GetCurrentUser();

function GetCurrentUser() {
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";

var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

$.ajax({
  url : requestUri,
  contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
  headers : requestHeaders,
  success : onSuccess,
  error : onError
  });
}

function onSuccess(data, request) {
    var loginName = data.d.Title;
    alert("Hello " + loginName);

    // to set the "hello username" into the page
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Hello " + loginName;
    }

function onError(error) {
  alert(error);
  }

</script>
```

The alertbox will show you something like: "Hello Firstname Lastname"

Also you can use `data.d.LoginName.split('|')[1]` instead of `data.d.Title` and modify the output a little bit.

If you want to print the "Hello Username" directly to the page you can use:

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Hello " + loginName;
```

Comment: Hi Patrick thanks for this however i'm trying to add this to the page, not as a alert, but more to display as Text

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same to "Welcome the logged in user". Therefore you only have to set a id for your div where it should be shown and then put the id (e.g. id="welcome") into the code. document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "Hello " + loginName; Also updated the script.

Comment: Note: Guessing you use jQuery in your example (based on `$.ajax`). You can use `CurrentUser` as end point. You can use `$.getJSON` because OP is on _SharePoint Online_ (no need for _odata_ type). You can use jQuery to select and set value on element. E.g., `$.getJSON("/_api/Web/CurrentUser").done(function(user) { $('#id').text(user.data.d.Title); });`

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript Object Model can be very easily used to get the current user.

```
// Getting current user detail
function getCurrentUser() {
    try {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var tempcurrentUser = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        clientContext.load(tempcurrentUser); 
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            var index = tempcurrentUser.get_loginName().indexOf('|') + 1;
            var currentUser = tempcurrentUser.get_loginName().substring(index);
            alert('Hello ' + currentUser); // Here you will get name of the user

        }, queryFailure);
    }
    catch (err) {
        queryFailure();
    }
}

function queryFailure () {
    alert('error');
}

//You can call the function like this
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getCurrentUser);
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the display name and login id by passing the parameter EmailID

Answer (score 1):

Code given in the below link demonstrates how to get the current user name by using simple CSOM,

http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/get-current-logged-in-username-in-sharepoint-2013-using-javascript-20982.aspx

Comment: Also can check the following links,    http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/get-current-logged-in-user-name-in-sharepoint-online-20984.aspx

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/9/get-the-current-logged-user-name-in-sharepoint-2013-using-js.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the element '#name' for whatever your "hello, *userName*" is.

```
    function getCurrentUser() 
    {  
        console.log('Made it');
        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = ctx.get_web();
        var currentUserObj = web.get_currentUser();
        ctx.load(currentUserObj);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            function() 
            {
                var displayName = currentUserObj.get_title();           
                $('#name').val(displayName);
            }, 
                function(sender, args) 
                {
                     console.log("An error occured: " + args.get_message());
                }); //end get currentUser display
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Best and simple way to get current logged in user name is _spPageContextInfo.

**_spPageContextInfo :**

`_spPageContextInfo` is a global variable usually available on any SharePoint page. This variable stores basic information about current web and current user.

Below are the Some examples:

**1. To Get User Display Name:**

`<script type="text/javascript">
 var currentUserName=_spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName;
 </script>`

*Eg: "Vishal"*

**2. To Get User Login Name:**

`<script type="text/javascript">
 var currentUserLoginName=_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName;
 </script>`

*Eg: "Vishal@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com"*

**3. To Get User Id:**

`<script type="text/javascript">
 var userID=_spPageContextInfo.userId;
 </script>`

*Eg:10*

**4. To Get Web Title:**

`<script type="text/javascript">
 var currentWebTitle=_spPageContextInfo.webTitle;
 </script>`

*Eg: "My Team Site"*

**To view all properties :**

Right click on page -->  click on "View Page Source" --> Find "_spPageContextInfo"

Comment: _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName is undefined

Comment: Note:  `_spPageContextInfo.userId` actually only gives a number, not the `domain\username` like one might think.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility that doesn't require javascript and will play nicely in scenarios where you cannot deploy custom server side code (locked down on-prem environments, SP Hosted apps/add-ins, or SharePoint Online (Office 365)...

If you have ability to modify (master) page (i.e. with SharePoint Designer), you might consider placing an [ASP.NET LoginControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginname.formatstring(v=vs.110).aspx) on the page.  This wouldn't require javascript at all (note that it displays the RAW username, not the friendly display name):

```
<asp:LoginName runat="server" id="loginName" FormatString="Hello, {0}"></asp:LoginName>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert("Hello " + _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName);
```

You can use it as per your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var loginName = "";
var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
GetCurrentUser();

function GetCurrentUser() {
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";

var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

$.ajax({
  url : requestUri,
  contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
  headers : requestHeaders,
  success : onSuccess,
  error : onError
  });
}

function onSuccess(data, request) {
    var loginName = data.d.Title;
    alert("Hello " + loginName);

    // to set the "hello username" into the page
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Hello " + loginName;
    }

function onError(error) {
  alert(error);
  }

</script>
```